# Using datetime lookback periods to record whether event occured in r

Tags: r, datetime, dplyr

I would like to transform this dataframe:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
EVENT <- c("HR", "RR", "HR, "CREATITINE", "HR")
DATETIME <- c("2019-08-01 00:00:01", "2019-08-01 00:30:00", "2019-08-01 01:30:00", "2019-08-01 02:00:00", "2019-08-01 05:00:00")         
LOOK_BACK_HOURS <- c(1,1,1,3,1)     
df <- data.frame(EVENT, DATETIME, LOOK_BACK_HOURS) 
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(DATETIME = ymd_hms(DATETIME))
```

| EVENT | DATETIME | LOOK_BACK_HOURS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| HR | 2019-08-01 00:00:01 | 1 |
| RR | 2019-08-01 00:35:00 | 1 |
| HR | 2019-08-01 01:30:00 | 1 |
| CREATININE | 2019-08-01 02:00:00 | 3 |
| HR | 2019-08-01 05:00:00 | 1 |

Into a dataframe that looks like this:

| EVENT | DATETIME | LOOK_BACK_HOURS | HR_FLAG | RR_FLAG | CREATININE_FLAG |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| HR | 2019-08-01 00:00:01 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| RR | 2019-08-01 00:35:00 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| HR | 2019-08-01 01:30:00 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| CREATININE | 2019-08-01 02:00:00 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| HR | 2019-08-01 05:00:00 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |

The flag will indicate if there has been an event of that type during the look back period. There is no requirement to count how times a particular type of event occurred, only if it happened or not.

Ideally I would like a dplyr solution, but given that my actual dataset will contain 9 event types and a couple of million rows of medical observations, a performant solution will greatly speed up running this across new datasets as they arise.

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain the logic behind `HR_FLAG`, `RR_FLAG` and `CREATININE_FLAG`

Comment: The flag will indicate if there has been an event of that type during the look back period. There is no requirement to count how times a particular type of event occurred, only if it happened or not.

Comment: What do you mean by look back period?

Comment: The lookback period would include observations that occurred after datetime - look_back_hours.  So if I'm looking at an HR observation that occured at 5pm, and the look_back_hours for HR is 1, I would like to flag if any of the other events occurred between 4pm and 5pm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a function like this and can use `purrr::map` to get the required data frame.

To find out the range of time I created a new column based on `LOOK_BACK_HOURS`. With this, I'll check the given times for different events falls within this range, if so I'll add a flag.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date, intersect, setdiff, union
EVENT <- c("HR", "RR", "HR", "CREATITINE", "HR")
DATETIME <- c("2019-08-01 00:00:01", "2019-08-01 00:30:00", "2019-08-01 01:30:00", "2019-08-01 02:00:00", "2019-08-01 05:00:00")         
LOOK_BACK_HOURS <- c(1,1,1,3,1)     
df <- data.frame(EVENT, DATETIME, LOOK_BACK_HOURS) 
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(DATETIME = ymd_hms(DATETIME))

flag <- function(start, end, event, dff = df){
  
  dff %>% 
    filter(EVENT == event) %>% 
    pull(DATETIME) -> times
  
  ifelse(times >= start & times <= end, 1, 0) %>% 
    sum() -> flag_count
  
  ifelse(flag_count > 0, 1, 0)

}

df %>% 
  mutate(look_back_time = DATETIME - (LOOK_BACK_HOURS*60*60),
         HR_FLAG = pmap_dbl(list(look_back_time, DATETIME, "HR"), flag),
         RR_FLAG = pmap_dbl(list(look_back_time, DATETIME, "RR"), flag),
         CREATITINE_FLAG = pmap_dbl(list(look_back_time, DATETIME, "CREATITINE"), flag)) %>% 
  select(-look_back_time)
#>        EVENT            DATETIME LOOK_BACK_HOURS HR_FLAG RR_FLAG
#> 1         HR 2019-08-01 00:00:01               1       1       0
#> 2         RR 2019-08-01 00:30:00               1       1       1
#> 3         HR 2019-08-01 01:30:00               1       1       1
#> 4 CREATITINE 2019-08-01 02:00:00               3       1       1
#> 5         HR 2019-08-01 05:00:00               1       1       0
#>   CREATITINE_FLAG
#> 1               0
#> 2               0
#> 3               0
#> 4               1
#> 5               0
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I tried it on a small sample and it worked well.It is currently churning through around 400000 rows and has been going for  around 30 minutes. This makes me wonder if for this kind of operation we could make use of multicores?

Comment: Yes, this solution is not efficient, you can take the filtering the data frame out of the function and instead pass a vector of filter data for each flag separately. Then you can see `furrr` package for parallelising this code.